# Python: Sphinx does not output transitions

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to document a package I am writing as a web page. Each member of the package has a docstring, and I use `autosummary` to automatically convert those into individual rst file.

My issue is that I am unable to use transitions to print horizontal lines in the html output (by using `----`). Whenever I add one of those, Sphinx outputs an error message and the generated html does not contain a transition.

Here is a minimal example. The function below belongs to `my_module`.

```
def foobar():
    r"""Foo

    ----

    Bar
    """
    pass
```

This is my Sphinx's main `index.rst` file:

```
.. autosummary::
    :toctree: _api_members

    my_module.foobar
```

Trying to make the html will output the following message:

`docstring of my_module.foobar:3: WARNING: Unexpected section title or transition.`

And as can be seen below, the output does not contain the expected transition.

[image]

The only way I found to solve this is to use raw html to print a `<hr>`, but this is really inelegant solution that polutes the docstrings.

```
def foobar():
    r"""Foo

    .. raw:: html

        <hr>

    Bar
    """
    pass
```

Producing the expected output with the horizontal rule:

[image]

I believe the only changes I did to my default `conf.py` are:

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
]

autosummary_generate = True
autosummary_imported_members = True
```

So my question is how can I print horizontal rules in the html output without having to manually add raw html code to my docstrings?

Comment: Use custom styles to render space and an `<hr>`.

Comment: @StevePiercy Thanks for the comment. Do you know if there is any documentation for that?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the theme you use and version of Sphinx, and there are several different ways of doing it. Personally I prefer specifying a custom `.css` file and including it via [`html_css_files`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files). This might not work with `sphinx_rtd_theme` and other themes, because their templates might list CSS files in an order that overrides your custom CSS.

Comment: Thanks once again. I am indeed using `sphinx_rtd_theme`, and my Sphinx version is 3.1.0, which is the latest available through `pip` on my machine. I will look into using a custom `.css` file, though I was hoping there were an easier solution for such a trivial task as using a transition, which is part of the [rst specification](https://docutils.readthedocs.io/en/sphinx-docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html?#transitions). All that I want is to have some sort of clear separator between different chunks with examples of features and usage of the members of my API.

Comment: I'd suggest submitting a [feature request to Sphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues). There might be something special about how Sphinx processes docstrings with `autodoc`.

Comment: @StevePiercy Thank you once again, I really appreciate your comments. I did as you suggested and opened a feature request. Just for future reference, the link to the request in their repo is: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7813

Comment: @StevePiercy conceptually, I think something isn't right about the aim of putting a transition inside a docstring. Because a transition or section is a structural part of a reST document, while a docstring is by nature atomic. Reexamining the aim, it seeks to make the most of the `autosummary` automatism, only to circumvent writing a detailed  `.rst` file. (And this is a pitfall that programmers just starting out with Sphinx expect: a magic javadoc like automatism that would spare them having to minutely customize their `.rst`.)

Comment: @gilbertohasnofb please don't take the above comment the wrong way. I thought about writing my docstrings like you propose (with transitions and sections). The above comment are basically the conclusions I arrived at. (Notice also, that if you're working in a larger project, should you want to change presentation/style, you'd be left with the problem of having to alter your docstrings instead of altering only the .rst. So you see it would be a bad design option for autodoc to allow this because it would cause problems down the road by inadvertence.)

Comment: @bad_coder I do not use sections in docstrings, but I do write very detailed explanations of how the classes are supposed to work, with many examples, warnings, tips, etc. This is in line with other libraries in my field, which is quite specific and is often aimed at non-coders. Even if you yourself think that using transitions is a bad idea, there is no reason why they cannot be supported by Sphinx; case and point, you also said sections are a bad idea, and yet they are currently supported. I understand your comment comes from a good place but it does not help with my question I am afraid.

Comment: Just correcting myself above: it seems traditional rst sections are not implemented in Sphinx, they only allow a handful of specially defined docstring sections as shown [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html).